# How to insert special symbol in a picture

Tags: latex

[image: picture]

I had tried this code and I want the braces in the figure as there are in the attached picture.

```
\begin{figure}[hbt!]
\begin{center}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[
       thick,
       acteur/.style={
         circle,
         fill=black,
         thick,
         inner sep=2pt,
         minimum size=0.2cm
       }
     ] 

           \node (a1) at (-0.3,0.65) [acteur,label=below :\scriptsize{}]{};
           \node (a2) at (1,0)[acteur,label=below:\scriptsize{\hspace{0.3cm}$x_{0}$}]{}; 
           \node (a3) at (2,0) [acteur,label=below:\scriptsize{$x_{1}$}]{}; 
           \node (a4) at (3,0) [acteur,label=below:\scriptsize{$x_{2}$}]{};
           \node (a5) at (4,0) [acteur,label=above :\scriptsize{}]{};
           \node (a6) at (5,0) [acteur,label=below right :\scriptsize{\hspace{-0.9cm}$x_{k-s-t}$}]{};
           \node (a7) at (6.5,0) [acteur,label=below:\scriptsize{}]{}; 
           \node (a8) at (-0.3,-0.65) [acteur,label=above:\scriptsize{}]{}; 
           \node (a9) at (0.4,1.3) [acteur,label=above:\scriptsize{}]{};
           \node (a10) at (0.4,-1.3) [acteur,label=below:\scriptsize{}]{}; 
           \node (a11) at (6,1) [acteur,label=below:\scriptsize{}]{};
           \node (a12) at (6,-1) [acteur,label=below:\scriptsize{}]{};
           \node (a13) at (5.3,1.3) [acteur,label=below:\scriptsize{}]{};
           \node (a14) at (5.3,-1.3) [acteur,label=below:\scriptsize{}]{};



           \draw  (a1) -- (a2); 
           \draw  (a2) -- (a9); 
           \draw  (a2) -- (a8);
           \draw  (a2) -- (a10);
           \draw  (a2) -- (a3);
           \draw  (a3) -- (a4);
           \draw [dashed]  (a4) -- (a5);
           \draw  (a5) -- (a6);
           \draw  (a6) -- (a7);
           \draw  (a6) -- (a11);
           \draw  (a6) -- (a13);
           \draw  (a6) -- (a12);
           \draw  (a6) -- (a14);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\caption{\small{The graph $\mathcal{P}(k,s,t)$}}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `decorations` library

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[hbt!]

  \begin{center}

  \begin{tikzpicture}[
     thick,
     acteur/.style={
       circle,
       fill=black,
       thick,
       inner sep=2pt,
       minimum size=0.2cm
       }
     ]

     \node (a1) at (-0.3,0.65) [acteur,label=below :\scriptsize{}]{};
     \node (a2) at (1,0)[acteur,label=below:\scriptsize{\hspace{0.3cm}$x_{0}$}]{};
     \node (a3) at (2,0) [acteur,label=below:\scriptsize{$x_{1}$}]{};
     \node (a4) at (3,0) [acteur,label=below:\scriptsize{$x_{2}$}]{};
     \node (a5) at (4,0) [acteur,label=above :\scriptsize{}]{};
     \node (a6) at (5,0) [acteur,label=below right :\scriptsize{\hspace{-0.9cm}$x_{k-s-t}$}]{};
     \node (a7) at (6.5,0) [acteur,label=below:\scriptsize{}]{};
     \node (a8) at (-0.3,-0.65) [acteur,label=above:\scriptsize{}]{};
     \node (a9) at (0.4,1.3) [acteur,label=above:\scriptsize{}]{};
     \node (a10) at (0.4,-1.3) [acteur,label=below:\scriptsize{}]{};
     \node (a11) at (6,1) [acteur,label=below:\scriptsize{}]{};
     \node (a12) at (6,-1) [acteur,label=below:\scriptsize{}]{};
     \node (a13) at (5.3,1.3) [acteur,label=below:\scriptsize{}]{};
     \node (a14) at (5.3,-1.3) [acteur,label=below:\scriptsize{}]{};



     \draw  (a1) -- (a2);
     \draw  (a2) -- (a9);
     \draw  (a2) -- (a8);
     \draw  (a2) -- (a10);
     \draw  (a2) -- (a3);
     \draw  (a3) -- (a4);
     \draw [dashed]  (a4) -- (a5);
     \draw  (a5) -- (a6);
     \draw  (a6) -- (a7);
     \draw  (a6) -- (a11);
     \draw  (a6) -- (a13);
     \draw  (a6) -- (a12);
     \draw  (a6) -- (a14);

     \draw[decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=10pt}]
     (-0.5, -1) -- (-0.5, 1) node[left, midway, xshift = -10pt]{$s$ vertices};

     \draw[decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=10pt}]
     (6.5, 1) -- (6.5, -1) node[right, midway, xshift = 10pt]{$t$ vertices};

   \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{center}

   \caption{\small{The graph $\mathcal{P}(k,s,t)$}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]